# johnny-five stepper move in (for-loop)

Tags: javascript, node.js, arduino, johnny-five

i'm relatively  new in node.js resp. johnny-five.
I'm trying to move a Stepper for (example) 5 times with 1000 Steps.

So:

```
   do 1000 Steps in cw ; 
   console.log('ready); 
   do 1000 steps;
   console.log('ready')
   ...
```

it would be nice to make this in a for loop .
 Example: for 5 times make 1000 steps. 
I try to do this with the following Code:

```
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    stepper.direction(1).step(1000, function() {
    console.log("Done stepping!");
    });
  }
```

The Output in my cmd is

```
Done stepping!
Done stepping!
Done stepping!
Done stepping!
Done stepping!
```

But the Motor moves only once. I don't really understand why!?

Hope someone can give a tip,
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Without wiring one up myself, I think that your problem is this: `direction(1)`. It seems like `direction` makes the motor point at a certain direction; thus your loop tells the motor to point at the same direction 5 times.

Try setting some different values inside `stepper()`, or replacing `1` with `i` in your loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   stepper.direction(i).step(1000, function() {
   console.log("Done stepping!");
   });
 }
```

If this doesn't help, does your stepper motor have an external power source? Can you provide a wiring diagram and the code for a simple test case?

Answer (score -1):

I am just starting to get back into writing code. It's been 30 years so I am more than rusty.

Try removing 'var in your 'for' loop.

```
 for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    stepper.direction(1).step(1000, function() {
    console.log("Done stepping!");
    });
  }
```

var I think would need to be defined earlier in the code.

If you found the reason why please post it so I can learn from it too.
Thanks